# Is there any reason some pins don't not work as GPIO on ATmega?

Tags: atmega, gpio, output, tri-state

I got an ATmega8515 and this simple code inside main():

```
void main(void) {
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    PORTD = 0xFF;

    while(1){}
}
```

I expect to see all the pins high, but PD5-PD7 are still in hi-Z state. No alternative function is configured - these are the first lines of the function! Any ideas please? Is it a compiler bug?

Have tried this on two MCUs bought from different suppliers, not likely for both to be defective.

P.S. I use cross-avr-gcc 5.4.0-1.14 under openSUSE 42.3

P.P.S. Once in awhile I faced something similar, playing with optimization (-O) flags helped. Does not do now.

Comment: How do you know/what makes you think they are in tri-state mode? (I assume that's what you mean.)

Comment: Also, what happens when you set a break point just after the PORTD = 0xFF; line? How do the pins look then?

Comment: The pin looks like low on oscilloscope, but when I try to load it with a LED through 1K resistor (another side goes to power bus) it goes high. Other pins of the port works fine with LED.

Comment: Is this after setting a breakpoint after the PORTD = 0xFF; line?

Comment: I don't have hadware suitable for debug. The loop prevents futher execution, and there is no other code other than this in the program. Also, everything works fine with any other ports and bits.

Comment: IMHO you need to get a debugger and be able to single step through programs. It will save you so much time (and by extension money) in the long run. Rowley Crossworks runs on Linux, works beautifully and is a sensible price.

Comment: Have you tried on more than one chip?

Comment: Yes I did. One bought several years ago and one bought a week ago. All the same.

Comment: Have you decompiled the code to see if it matches expectations?

Comment: Well I am not good with decompiling and assembly code. Internet says about enabled JTAG interface, but it is disabled by default - and I also tried to do this manually by setting the bits. Eventually had to use another pins for this device. If someone is skilled enough to play with decompiler, I can provide my project so one could create a bug report for the cross compiler developers.